# SASL - LDAP: error code 49 - 80090303: LdapErr: DSID-0C09054F, comment: The digest-uri does not match any LDAP SPN's registered for this server

Tags: active-directory, ldap, sasl

I'm trying to update the user password for a user in Microsoft Active Directory with LDAP, using JNDI library over **SASL (DIGEST-MD5)**. And there are a couple of issues that makes the operation fail.

**First issue**

During the authentication phase, I receive the error
`Exception: #javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090303: LdapErr: DSID-0C09054F, comment: The digest-uri does not match any LDAP SPN's registered for this server., data 0, v2580`

**Steps taken**

I added the required SPN to the DC in AD, and the issue was resolved only for one time, then it came back. When I checked the DC, I found out that the SPN that I have just added has been removed. And this keeps happening every time I add the SPN to the DC!

**Second issue**

During the time that the authentication proceeds successfully, the server refuses to update the user's password. I'm trying to update the "unicodePwd" attribute using a "DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE" operation (I'm using a domain controller administrator account for the authentication, and trying to update a normal user account).

This is the error I receive "Error:
`#javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 53 - 0000001F: SvcErr: DSID-031A12D2, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0 ]; remaining name '<the DN of the user that I was trying to update>'`

Another note, when I check the attribute "unicodePwd", it's always unset!! So, the question here "How does the AD authenticate the user? Which attribute holds the user's password?!!

**Third issue**

I can use a couple of LDAP clients, and I can update/reset the user's password. I only need to specify the authentication protocol as (SASL) and the operation goes seamlessly =, without having to make any Changes to the AD/SC!

This is the code sample I'm using

```java
    // Session variables
    String adminUsername = "<administrator sAMAccountName value>";
    String adminPwd = "<admin password>";
    String userDN = "<DN for the user being updated>";
    String newPwd = "<The new password for the user being updated>";
    String ipAddress = "<AD ip address>";

    // LDAP configuration
    String securityProtocol = "sasl";
    String providerURL = "ldap://" + ipAddress;

    Hashtable<Object, Object> env = new Hashtable<>();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put("javax.security.sasl.strength", "high");
    env.put("javax.security.sasl.policy.noplaintext", "true");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, providerURL);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "DIGEST-MD5");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, adminUsername);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, adminPwd);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, securityProtocol); 
    env.put(Context.REFERRAL, "follow");

    // Prepare the modifications list 
    String newQuotedPassword = "\"" + newPwd + "\"";
    byte[] newUnicodePassword = newQuotedPassword.getBytes("UTF-16LE");
    ModificationItem[] mods = new ModificationItem[1];
    mods[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, 
            new BasicAttribute("unicodePwd", newUnicodePassword));

    // Initiate the LDAP connection
    LdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);

    // Modify the password
    ctx.modifyAttributes(userDN, mods);

    // Close LDAP connection
    ctx.close();
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a good deal of R&D. There is no way to update the password in the AD without using SSL. Java and MS AD are very strict on that.